# How to find previous and next emails in mu4e

Tags: email, mu4e

Say that I'm looking at an email that's part of a chain in `mu4e` and I want to find the next and previous emails. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is easy. If you're viewing the message (i.e. in mu4e:view), you can hit `a` (for "action") then `s` (for "show this thread").